# Method with to much responsibility using the repository pattern (C#)

Tags: c#

So Iv'e just started out with the basics of the repository pattern and I seem to struggling with "what goes where".

I have a method that inserts a user from a create account page.

FrontEnd:

```
using (UserRepository userRepo = new UserRepository()) 
{
  userRepo.Add(some params here);
}
```

BackEnd:

```
/// <summary>
/// Inserts a new user to the db
/// </summary>
/// <param name="encryptedPassword">Encrypted Password</param>
/// <param name="email">Plain text email</param>
/// <param name="tokenId">Security Token ID</param>
/// <param name="encryptedEmail">Encrypted Password</param>
public void Add(string encryptedPassword, string email, string encryptedEmail, string firstName, string surName)
{
   //try { }
   //catch { }

   //Create Token
   string guid = System.Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
   tbl_Token newToken = new tbl_Token();
   newToken.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
   newToken.Name = guid;
   _context.tbl_Token.Add(newToken);

   //Create User
   tbl_User createUser = new tbl_User();
   createUser.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
   createUser.IsAccountConfirmed = false;
   createUser.Email = email;
   createUser.EncryptedEmail = encryptedEmail;
   createUser.EncryptedPassword = encryptedPassword;
   createUser.TokenId = newToken.TokenId;
   _context.tbl_User.Add(createUser);

   //Create Bio
   tbl_Bio newBio = new tbl_Bio();
   newBio.UserId = createUser.UserId;
   newBio.FirstName = firstName;
   newBio.LastName = surName;
   newBio.ProfilePic = "avatar.png";
   newBio.DateAdded = DateTime.Now;
   _context.tbl_Bio.Add(newBio);

}
```

When I was crafting this I instantly knew that there was a code smell and this method contained to much responsibility. On the action of a user clicking a button it should create a Token then create a User which access's TokenId and then it Creates a Bio which access's the UserId. So it's all relational.

Should the UserRepo have a dependency on the TokenRepo and BioRepo? (Having said that with new DB contexts it would lose the memory allocation of the Id's of each new repo instantiation)

What would be the "Cleanest" way of passing around newly inserted unique Id's?

Or is the above code snippet suitable?

Apologies if the explanation is lacking.

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In some ways, Yes. The code smells. Why, Because here you're introducing a hard coupling of references of Bio and Token.

What if in future you want to update the way Token is being created in application. You have to come back and update Add() method of User repository which makes no sense. As a good practice, Any change in classes should have minimal impact on other classes. Following practice to build a loosely coupled system.

Here the responsibility to supply the Token id which is required to Add user and User Id required to create Bio can be shifted to Caller and not of AddUser(). viz. Inversion of Control.

To minimize the coupling you can do something like below;

Let say, the caller is a method Registeration():

```
public void Registeration()
{
  // Create Token
  var TokenId = tokenRepo.Add();
  // Create user
  var UserId = userRepo.Add(TokenId, /*....params ... */);
  // Now add Bio
  var Bio = userBioRepo.Add(UserId, /*....params ... */);
}
```

Let the Add method only add user and get rid of Bio and Token creation.

Answer (score 0):

Instinct says the creation of all these should be separate, then wrapped up in a service layer of some sort within a transaction. The service layer would update/insert whatever is required and would need access to each repository involved.